# Why is OptiX using so much CPU instead of GPU?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I'm rendering an animation & chose OptiX since I have an RTX 2060 for my GPU. I also clicked on my CPU since I thought "Hybrid rendering is allowed so it must be faster" (I'm new to Blender).

However, when rendering, I notice that Blender is using a lot more of my CPU than GPU, even though my impression would be that using the GPU is faster.[image: Screenshot of resource consumption]

Any clues as to why this could be? Is it a feature?

Thank you!

Comment: Task manager reports gpu 3d rasterization engine usage instead of CUDA or RT core usage by default

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116486/110840